# Desenhar triângulo com estrutura de repetição em Python

Tags: python

Preciso desenhar um triângulo da forma:

```
....1
...12
..123
.1234
12345
```

Devo usar estruturas de repetição. Pelo que entendi como dica, devo usar duas estruturas concatenadas.
Sou iniciante e já tentei diversas vezes mas não está saindo.

Um exemplo do que tentei:

```
n = int(input())

def triângulo2(n):
  
  s = ''
  i = n
  c = 1
  while i>=1:
    s = s + str('.')
    print(s)
    i = i-1
triângulo2(n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa é fazer um *loop* de 1 até n, ir aumentando o número (acrescentando o novo dígito no final) e imprimir usando as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
def triangulo(n):
    x = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        x = i + (x * 10)
        print(f'{x:.>{n}}')

triangulo(5)
```

A cada iteração eu multiplico o número por 10 e somo o novo dígito (assim, 1 se torna 12, que depois se torna 123, etc).

Para imprimir eu uso `.>{n}`, que diz para imprimir o número alinhado à direita (`>`), ocupando `n` posições e preenchendo os espaços faltantes com o ponto.

---

Claro que também dá pra fazer concatenando strings:

```
def triangulo(n):
    x = '1'
    pontos = '.' * (n - 1)
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(f'{pontos}{x}')
        x += str(i + 1) # adiciona um dígito
        pontos = pontos[:-1] # remove um ponto 

triangulo(5)
```

Mas eu acho desnecessário ficar criando tantas strings (cada iteração cria uma nova string para o "número" e outra para os pontos), quando algumas contas simples e o uso das opções de formatação já resolvem.

Comment: Muito bom! obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
A princípio pode parecer um pouco complexo, mas basta utilizar 2 métodos de listas em Python para te ajudar.
O que você precisará fazer é criar uma lista preenchendo-a com os pontos '.'
Os 2 métodos que irão te auxiliar serão o .pop() que remove uma posição específica de uma lista (a última caso nada seja passado) e o .append() que irá adicionar um elemento ao final da lista. Entendendo estes 2 métodos, facilmente você irá conseguir resolver o problema.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lista.pop(0)
# A lista agora eh: [2, 3, 4, 5]

lista.append(6)
# A lista agora eh: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Uma outra dica é utilizar o lista.pop(0) no while! Como condição de parada.

Comment: Não conhecia o pop, muito bom!